# How to access a value of an array within an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
$array = array(
    array('id' => 'test1', 
          'url' => 'test1url'
    ),

    array('id' => 'test2', 
          'url' => 'test2url'
    )
);
```

How to access "test1url" without knowing the parent key but knowing the corresponding ID (test1)?
If I knew the parent key I could simply access it like this:

```
$array[0]['url'];
```

So what would be the simplest/fastest/quickest/easiest way to access this value?

Thanks!

Comment: Iterate over the array with `foreach` maybe? Depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @fireeyedboy I have edited the question to specify that the ID in the same array is the criterion!

Comment: @FelixKling Yes but I was looking for a lighter solution than looping through all values!

Comment: @gorge where does the array come from?

Comment: Well, if you don't know which array the value contains, then you don't have any other choice than iterating over the outer array in one way or the other.

Comment: @meze the array is hard-coded. **I could definitely put the IDs in the parent array keys**, but it would require me to rewrite some other code where this array is referred to, and before I do that I wanted to make sure that it was the only solution to avoid a foreach on the array just to find the value! Thanks again all for the quick answers ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no solution better than looping all values in this case.

You can create a function like this:

```
function findUrl($array,$id) {
    foreach($array as $arr) {
        if($arr['id'] == $id) {
            return $arr['url'];
        }
    }
}
```

and call it:

```
echo findUrl($array,"test1");
```

or create another representation of your data, but if you cannot do it, the best solution is this loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    array('id' => 'test1', 'url' => 'test1url'),
    array('id' => 'test2', 'url' => 'test2url')
);

$search = 'test1url';
foreach($array as $k=>$a){
    if(is_array($a) && in_array($search,$a)){
        echo "Key:".$k." has responded that the value of ".array_search($search,$a).' = '.$search;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that you build your array like that? What is the function of the parent array?

You could use: array_search();

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

But that would only work if you loop the parent array first.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array('id' => 'test1', 
          'url' => 'test1url'
    ),

    array('id' => 'test2', 
          'url' => 'test2url'
    )
);


foreach ($array as $valuearray) {
    $key = array_search('test1url', $valuearray);
    echo $key;  // = url
}
?>
```

Or use in_array(); when looping the parent array.